# Github push notification could not resolve host

Tags: github

I run this `Git` command:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/vgonzalezfranchi/my-first-blog.git
```

But then when I try:

```
git push -u origin master
```

I get the following error:

> fatal unable to access "https://vgonzalezfranchi/my-first-blog.git/":
>   Could not resolve host: vgonzalezfranchi

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Check the url with `git remote show origin` it is not correct following your error.

Answer (score 0):

The URL stated in the error-message is **missing** the **github.com** domain. If you have trouble furthermore try:

```
touch initial
git add initial
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

and then

```
git push -u origin master
```

---

Make sure you have the required access rights. I strongly recommend working with ssh-key's.